# Android - EulerZ value is fluctuated consistently in Face detection

Tags: android, android-camera, face-detection, android-vision

I am trying to get EulerZ axis value in face detection. I have used `com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.0.1` library for the same.

When I try to turn my face, I'm getting EulerZ axis value and when I make my face in steady position but EulerZ axis value is getting changed. I have set Face detector properties as following,

```
FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector.Builder(FaceTrackerActivity.this)
                .setTrackingEnabled(false)
                .setLandmarkType(FaceDetector.ALL_LANDMARKS)
                .setMode(FaceDetector.ACCURATE_MODE)
                .setClassificationType(FaceDetector.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
                .build();
```

And I'm getting EulerZ value from

```
float eulerZ = face.getEulerZ();
```

Let me know if I'm missing anything to initialize. Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you to use FAST_MODE instead of ACCURATE_MODE. It is much faster and provides very similar results. Also, if you are tying it on a live preview, it will be better to set Trancking Enabled to True